# I need help getting imports to resolve for discord and doten v to work (I'm new to coding)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, discord, dotenv

[error type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVOog.png)

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I tried finding solutions to this problem through the power of what's already on the internet, but the answers I found seemed like they'd be outdated.

Comment: Please post the error. Also make sure that python -m pip list includes both dependencies.

Comment: What exactly is the error you’re getting?

Comment: Added a screenshot at the top